# Unable to access Windows files running Ubuntu from a USB drive

Tags: boot, usb

My 8.1 stuffed up! It doesn't load Windows and instead keeps saying Windows is repairing the problem and will restart. It keeps on restarting time and time again.

So I've mounted the latest version of Ubuntu onto a USB drive. Changed my computers settings to disable fast boot and made the USB drive a priority when booting. I did this in the menu by pressing F2 when I start the computer. I cannot change it in the power options in Windows because I can't open it.

I press try Ubuntu and when I go into the computer I can't open the hard drives it shows there because of the following message.

I tried following instructions given here but still cannot access the drives.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/

http://imageshack.com/a/img841/9659/dqhgu.jpg

Please help as I wish to save some of my files onto an external USB before sending the computer back to the manufacturer where it will most likely be formatted.

Regards

Comment: _I press try Ubuntu and when I go into the computer I can't open the hard drives it shows there because of the following message._ Which message?

Comment: unable to access "HDD" see the photo please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to read files from it, did you try following the instructions in the error message, and mounting with the read-only option `ro`?

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/disk -o force,ro
```

Comment: should I just change the o to an ro or write out the whole line?

Comment: Sorry, my options were wrong. I'd edited the answer.

Comment: I am currently copying files from internal to external drive. hopefully I can do the same for the other internal drive. Then if I'm extra lucky there may be a way for me to reinstall everything to factory settings without sending it back to the manufacturer.

Comment: Good luck! (You should also "fix it" in the long term by uninstalling Windows and installing Linux. ☺)

Comment: I've used Linux before and the only reason I am using Windows is not because I like it but because that's what I need to run a program.

Comment: Okay, no worries. I was being slightly facetious anyway. :)